# REGEXP_SUBSTR, REPLACE, and TO_NUMBER

Tags: sql, replace, regexp-substr

I have two tables like this:

```
| MOVIE_ID | BUDGET      |
|----------+-------------|
|  1904269 | $850,000    |
|  1809508 | NLG 800,000 |
|  1988471 | $40,000     |
|  2119404 | $3,266      |
|  2117105 | $125,000    |
|  2167227 | CAD 280,000 |
```

and

```
| MOVIE_ID | GROSS                  |
|----------+------------------------|
|  2463072 | ESP 20,040,964 (Spain) |
|  2044720 | ESP 7,494,043 (Spain)  |
|  2083304 | ESP 53,463,024 (Spain) |
|  2461323 | ESP 15,670,733 (Spain) |
|  2318432 | ESP 16,530,040 (Spain) |
|  1874413 | SEK 512,112 (Sweden)   |
```

I want to create a budget_table which contains pairs of movie_id's and movie budgets. The movie budgets are stored as strings in movie_info. We only need to consider budgets which are listed in dollars, i.e. "$ XXXXXX". I also want to create a gross_table which contains pairs of movie_id's and movie gross revenues. Some movies have multiple gross revenues (i.e. the revenue as of 2008, 2010, 2012, etc.), and we just want the largest one. Then, I need to find the most profitable one by gross - budget. The two tables above I got by using the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW budget_table AS 
SELECT movie_id, info AS budget 
FROM movie_info WHERE info_type_id = 105;
```

so the budget info has id = 105.
And the gross info has id = 107 and the code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW gross_table AS 
SELECT movie_id, info AS gross 
FROM movie_info WHERE info_type_id = 107;
```

Below is my code to get the budgets only listed in dollars:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW budget_table AS
SELECT movie_id, TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(info, '\$[0-9]+'), '\$', ''))
                       AS budget
                      FROM movie_info
                      WHERE info_type_id = 105
                      AND REGEXP_LIKE(info, '\$[0-9]+');
```

I have no idea why it didn't print out anything when I do `SELECT * FROM budget_table LIMIT 10;`. If I get rid of the last row `REGEXP_LIKE`, I get the movie_id but all nulls for the budget. Can someone point out the issue with my SQL query?

Comment: Don't cram multiple values into strings; use separate columns for currency_type, budget, gross and country. If your input data are these multiple-value strings, then parse it to split it up when inserting into tables.

Comment: I'm given the schema, not allowed to edit it so I can't use separate columns for currency_type, budget, gross or country.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your query involves several product specific functions.)

Comment: @jarlh I'm using snowflake

Answer (score 0):

I would look for few things below to debug the issue -

1. make sure if there a value with dollar sign followed by one or more digits.
   by just applying "regexp_substr(info,'$[0-9]+')" as budget_Col1, REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(info, '$[0-9]+'), '$', '') as budget_Col2
   To debug the issue with expression or if there no values in column with matching expression
2. And try the filter as
   select info,"regexp_substr(info,'$[0-9]+')" from your_table where "regexp_substr(info,'$[0-9]+')" is not null
3. And if there null in string column, try using
   "to_number(replace(replace(nvl(regexp_substr(info,'$[0-9]+'),'0'),'$',' '),',','')"

Hope this helps:)

Comment: I tried all three. Here's the issue: A subset of the data is shown above so there are definitely values with matching expression. Also tried 2 and 3 but it didn't work. :( I see so issues in my code though. The budget is in string, like the example above "$850,000". I just want to convert it to a number which I believe, my code is perfectly fine.

Comment: "to_number(replace(replace(nvl(regexp_substr(info,'\$[0-9]+'),'0'),'$',' '),',','')"

Comment: Thanks for fixing your code but it still outputted nothing, not even NULLs.

Comment: Can you please share sample value from info column, or can i assume the value as $850,000 for example?

Comment: I did share above in my question. The column:  | MOVIE_ID | BUDGET      |
|----------+-------------|
|  1904269 | $850,000    |
|  1809508 | NLG 800,000 |
|  1988471 | $40,000     |
|  2119404 | $3,266      |
|  2117105 | $125,000    |
|  2167227 | CAD 280,000 |

Comment: Thanks for providing again, i tried below in redshift, i think oracle does have same function SELECT regexp_replace('$850,000' , '[^0-9]+') as col1;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256761/discussion-between-hanamontana-and-shiva).

Comment: And in your condition to filter only dollar values where regexp_like(info,'\\$[0-9]+')

Comment: But the other budget is in different currency format. :\

Comment: i mean as below SELECT regexp_replace(info , '[^0-9]+') as col1 from your_table where regexp_like(info,'\\$[0-9]+');